# Private member of template class in the specialisation

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have a template class as following

```
template <typename T>
class Reader {
 public:
  Reader(std::string& filename, uint dummy_sid = 0) {...};
  bool isBroken() {return m_is_broken;}
  T getNext() {some operations; return m_event;}

 private:
  bool m_is_broken = false;
  uint m_dummy_sid = 0;
  T m_event;

};
```

And then I am creating two specialisations similar to the following one:

```
template<>
class Reader<NAME_A> {
 public:
  Reader(std::string& filename, uint dummy_sid = 0) {
    m_dummy_sid = dummy_sid;
    m_in_file = std::ifstream(filename);
  }
 private:
  std::ifstream m_in_file;
};
```

So I would like to add one private class member and redefining the constructor. During compilation it seems that for example in the specialisation the member `m_dummy_sid` is not seen (`error: m_dummy_sid' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'dummy_sid'?`). Clearly this is not the way to specialise and extend one class I guess. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the template specialization of class `dualReader` should have the same name as `Reader`.

```
template<>
class Reader<NAME_A> {
 public:
 .....
 .....
};
```

Secondly, the specialization of `Reader` template cannot the the members of non-specialized template `Reader`. This is because C++ actually threats the template specializations of classes as completely different types. The only relation it has to the original template is the name.

For your problem inheritance is more suitable. You can inherit from `Reader` class

```
template<class T>
class dualReader : public Reader<T>{
 public:
 .....
 .....
 private:
 std::ifstream m_in_file;
};
```

Also if you want derived class to access the members of the base class, you should declare the members of the base class as `protected`.

Comment: Correct on the first point, I just edited (forgot to change when preparing the simplified version). Ouch on the second point. So I basically have to duplicate code I guess.

Comment: Here the scope was to have a reader of different input file types. In most of the case the base template is fine, but then I wanted to add some more features for special types.

Comment: You still can add the features on derived classes. Can you be more specific on the features you intend to add?

Comment: Nothing special: in general I am passing txt files in input and I want a method which is hasNext() which is reading a line and doing a regex match. In a couple of cases I am passing in input a file which can be ready with a special class which has already something like that built-in, so hasNext() will be just a wrapper. In this way, in the main code, I will have the same reader object with same method names for all the cases.